# Using tryCatch with Magrittr pipes in R

Tags: r, try-catch, tidyverse, magrittr

I have two similar functions that I want to apply to a data frame. Each function uses two vectors from the data frame and creates a new vector. However, one of the functions sometimes returns errors. Ultimately, I am going to use this in a for-loop and count the number of errors that each function gives (to show that one function is better than the other :-)). However, I don't know if I understand `tryCatch` or `try` well enough to use with pipes. Below is an example of one time where a function would fail.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Function that works    
func_1 <- function(arg1, arg2) {
      arg1 + arg2
    }

# Function that errors
    func_2 <- function(arg1, arg2) {
      if(arg1 == 0) {error("Some Error")}
      else arg1 * arg2
    }

# Using the functions with pipes
    cars <- mtcars %>%
      filter(mpg > 18) %>%
      select("vs", "carb") %>%
      mutate(func1 = func_1(vs,carb)) %>%
      mutate(func1 = func_2(vs, carb))
```

When I wrap the mutate with a `try` then the new vector/column does not get computed. I can't get `tryCatch` to work using the pipes. Any thoughts or alternative approaches are appreciated.

Comment: What is your desired behaviour when there is some error?

Comment: I am going to loop through many data frames, so every time a functions doesn't work it could increment a counter: `func_2_errors = func_2_errors + 1`. If both functions work, the data frame should have 4 columns, if one function fails, the data frame should have 3 columns, if both fail, it should have just the original 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error_counting` function receives a function as a parameter and returns a function with same functionality and records the error times in a list called `error_numbers`. 
And if one function fails, the corresponding column of data frame will be `NA`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Function that works    
func_1 <- function(arg1, arg2) {
    arg1 + arg2
}

# Function that errors
func_2 <- function(arg1, arg2) {
    if (any(arg1 == 0)) {stop("Some Error")}
    else arg1 * arg2
}

error_numbers <- list()

error_counting <- function(f){
    force(f)
    fname <- as.character(substitute(f))
    error_numbers[[fname]] <<- 0
    count <- function(e){
        error_numbers[[fname]] <<- error_numbers[[fname]] + 1
        NA
    }
    function(...){
        tryCatch(f(...), error = count)
    }
}

e_func_1 <- error_counting(func_1)
e_func_2 <- error_counting(func_2)

# Using the functions with pipes
cars <- mtcars %>%
    filter(mpg > 18) %>%
    select(vs, carb) %>%
    mutate(func1 = e_func_1(vs,carb)) %>%
    mutate(func2 = e_func_2(vs, carb))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Function that works    
func_1 <- function(arg1, arg2) {
  arg1 + arg2
}

# Function that errors
func_2 <- function(arg1, arg2) {
  if (arg1 == 0) { error("Some Error") }
  else arg1 * arg2
}

countingly <- function (.f, handle = uuid::UUIDgenerate(), otherwise = NULL, quiet = TRUE) {
  .f <- as_function(.f)
  function(...) {
    ret <- purrr:::capture_error(.f(...), otherwise)
    if (is.null(ret$result)) {
      error_track <<- c(error_track, list(f_hand = handle, f_err = ret$error))
      NA
    } else {
      ret$result
    }
  }
}

s_func_1 <- countingly(func_1, "f1")
s_func_2 <- countingly(func_2, "f2")

error_track <- list()

cars <- mtcars %>%
  filter(mpg > 18) %>%
  select("vs", "carb") %>%
  mutate(func1 = s_func_1(vs, carb)) %>%
  mutate(func2 = s_func_2(vs, carb))
```